# generate leaflet markers from html-markup

Tags: jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I am looking for a way, to generate leaflet-markers from the html-content on a website.

I got this html-markup:

```
<div id="map"></div>

<div id="content">

<div class="mark">
    <h3>Mark #1</h3>
    <span class="title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span><br>    
    <span class="lat">53.922429</span><br>  
    <span class="lng">9.682042</span><br>   
</div> 

<div class="mark">
    <h3>Mark #1</h3>
    <span class="title">Consetetur sadipscing elitr</span><br>  
    <span class="lat">53.642978</span><br>  
    <span class="lng">10.613895</span><br>  
</div>      

<div class="mark">
    <h3>Mark #1</h3>
    <span class="title">Sed diam nonumy</span><br>  
    <span class="lat">53.146250</span><br>  
    <span class="lng">9.666947</span><br>   
</div> 

</div>
```

Now I like the markers to be generated from this markup as if I had this script attached:

```
<script>

L.mapbox.accessToken = '<myAccessToken>';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', '<myAccessID>').setView([51, 10], 6);
var cssIcon01 = L.divIcon({className: 'css-icon01',iconSize: [14, 14]});

L.marker([53.922429, 9.682042], {icon: cssIcon01, title: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor'}).addTo(map);
L.marker([53.642978, 10.613895], {icon: cssIcon01, title: 'Consetetur sadipscing elitr'}).addTo(map);
L.marker([53.146250, 9.666947], {icon: cssIcon01, title: 'Sed diam nonumy'}).addTo(map);

</script>
```

The markers should be generated dynamically, so that I can add as much markers as I like. I guess there will be variables and some foreach-script involved, but I just do not where to start.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any special difficulty in doing what you describe, especially since you seem to plan using jQuery.

1. Retrieve all your `div`'s with `"mark"` class: `var $marks = $(".mark")`
2. Create an iteration function and apply it to [each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) found node: `$marks.each(myFunction)`
3. Inside the `myFunction(indexInArray, mark)`, retrieve the data specific to the marker:

   - Title: `var title = $(".title", mark).text()`
   - Latitude: `var lat = parseFloat($(".lat", mark).text())`
   - Longitude: `var lng = parseFloat($(".lng", mark).text())`
4. Build your marker: `L.marker([lat, lng], {icon: cssIcon01, title: title}).addTo(map)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your advice! It got me on the right path, but I am still doing something wrong. This is what I have now:

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="mark">
            <h3>Mark #1</h3>
            <span class="title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span><br>    
            <span class="lat">53.922429</span><br>  
            <span class="lng">9.682042</span><br>   
        </div> 

        <div class="mark">
            <h3>Mark #2</h3>
            <span class="title">Consetetur sadipscing elitr</span><br>  
            <span class="lat">53.642978</span><br>  
            <span class="lng">10.613895</span><br>  
        </div> 

        <div class="mark">
            <h3>Mark #3</h3>
            <span class="title">Sed diam nonumy</span><br>  
            <span class="lat">53.146250</span><br>  
            <span class="lng">9.666947</span><br>   
        </div> 

</div>

<script>

    L.mapbox.accessToken = '<myToken>';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', '<myID>').setView([51, 10], 6);   // latitude, longitude, zoom level;  

    var cssIcon01 = L.divIcon({className: 'css-icon01',iconSize: [14, 14]});


    var $marks = $(".mark")
    $marks.each(function() {
            var title = $(".title", mark).text()
            var lat = parseFloat($(".lat", mark).text())
            var lng = parseFloat($(".lng", mark).text())
        L.marker([lat, lng], {icon: cssIcon01, title: title}).addTo(map);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fiddled around some more and with this script I finally got it working:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = '<myToken>';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', '<myID>').setView([51, 10], 6);   // latitude, longitude, zoom level;  

var cssIcon01 = L.divIcon({className: 'css-icon01',iconSize: [14, 14]});

$(".mark").each(function() {
        var title = $(this).find(".title").html()
        var lat = $(this).find(".lat").html();
        var lng = $(this).find(".lng").html();
        L.marker([lat, lng], {icon: cssIcon01, title: title}).addTo(map);           
});
```